# Jupyter notebook does not start when called from a conda virtual environment

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, jupyter

I am using Conda version 4.9.0 on MacOS Mojave.
When I call jupyter notebook from the base environment it works.
However, when I try to start a notebook from my virtual environment where Jupyter notebook is also installed (with `conda install -c conda-forge notebook`) I am getting this error:

> File "/Users/ilkay.isik/opt/anaconda3/envs/fccontent/bin/jupyter",
> line 11, in 
> sys.exit(main())   File "/Users/ilkay.isik/opt/anaconda3/envs/fccontent/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jupyter_core/command.py",
> line 247, in main
> command = _jupyter_abspath(subcommand)   File "/Users/ilkay.isik/opt/anaconda3/envs/fccontent/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jupyter_core/command.py",
> line 134, in _jupyter_abspath
> 'Jupyter command `{}` not found.'.format(jupyter_subcommand) Exception: Jupyter command `jupyter-notebook` not found.

I can't seem to understand this error and solve this problem. Can anyone direct me to a solution?

Comment: I use `jupyter notebook` command insted of `jupyter-notebook`

Comment: Is IPython installed in the venv?

Comment: @Patel I use ```jupyter notebook``` too, ```jupyter-notebook``` returns: ```jupyter-notebook: command not found```

Comment: @S3DEV yes it is installed

Comment: I tried to install it again with pip instead of conda 
```pip install notebook``` 
and now it seems to work...